# DeadlineExceedError on Ancestor queries

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm looking for advice on how to improve the performance of ancestor queries over large datasets. Currently, many of the ancestor queries take so long they through a DeadlineExceededError, while doing the same query without the ancestor filter works fine, if a bit slow.

The data is structured so that each kind Entity, which is the kind queried for, is nested under 3 entities of kind Parent. (e.g. the Entity key path would be ['Parent', 'keyname1', 'Parent', 'keyname2', 'Parent', 'keyname3', 'Entity', 'keyname4']

The query takes the form of:

```
Entity.all().ancestor(parentkey).filter('property IN', list)
```

where `list` is a list of at most 3 values and parentkey may be two or three levels above the entity in question.

Any ideas on what's going on here?

Comment: How many entities are in your entity groups? How often do your entity groups change?

Comment: Depending on the level of the ancestor, entity groups could have between a few hundred to a few thousand. Obviously, the ones giving the problem are toward the upper bound.